# How remove UITabBarController from UIViewController

Tags: iphone, ios, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

How to remove `UITabBarController` from `UIViewController`, when we are moving from one `UIViewController` to another `UIViewController` with `UINavigationController`.

Comment: Please be more detailed while asking the question.

Comment: Do you mean hide tabbar?

Answer (score 0):

Overwrite the init function in your code (**loadView probably won't work**)

```
self.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed = NO;
```

// OR you can remove it from app delegate by putting these lines in a method named by urself

[mainMenuTabBarController.view removeFromSuperview];

Answer (score 0):

You should set [this property](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIViewController/hidesBottomBarWhenPushed) of UIViewController to YES: `BOOL hidesBottomBarWhenPushed`

*Example:*
The second line of the code below is what you ask.

```
UIViewController *destinationVC = [[UIViewController alloc] init];
[destinationVC setHidesBottomBarWhenPushed:YES]; // !!!
[self.navigationController pushViewController:destinationVC animated:YES];
```

Answer (score -1):

```
[self.tabBarcontroller.view removeFromSuperview];
```

Answer (score -1):

```
[self.tabBarcontroller.view removeFromSuperview];
[self.tabBarcontroller.tabbar removeFromSuperview];
```

Answer (score -1):

```
UIViewController *yourController = [[UIViewController alloc] init];
[yourController setHidesBottomBarWhenPushed:YES]; 
[self.navigationController pushViewController:yourController animated:YES];
```

here you make a instance of your ViewController and then befor pushing it just use the setHidesBottomBarPushed() so that it is hidden when you push it.

But remember it will work only if u do this befor pushing.